# How to view the source (Landing Page) for any Visits to a group of pages

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to look at several pages in a group ( Page1.htm, Page2.htm, etc.) and then view the Landing Pages that originated that traffic.

Use Case:

I have several pages that indicate interest from the visitor.
I'd like to look at all Visits that passed through *any* of them and then see which pages generated the most visits. (The Pages are blog articles).

I can probably use Content Grouping to view the "several pages" as "one page".  So it may be sufficient to just view the source for a particular page (Content Group)

**What I Tried**

I Created a Content Grouping (Conversion Intent)
I went to the Behaviour > Landing Pages view and that shows me all the Landing Pages. Great!

But when I select  the Content Group above,  the list of landing pages goes away and I only see totals. (See screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: I saw in your other question you were trying to create an advanced segment with the content grouping you created.  Have you tried to create the advanced segment with the page URLs directly?